# How one function access a variable value from another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```js
let count = 0;

function increment(){ 
    count += 1;
    console.log(count); 
}

function decrement(){ 
    count -= 1;
    console.log(count); 
}

increment();
decrement();
```

Calling `increment()` will give `count = 1` and then calling `decrement()` will give `count = 0`. How does the second function get the value of count from the first function ?

Comment: They're both accessing the same global variable. What's the problem?

Comment: It won't; it will get the value of `count` from `count`, a global variable.

Comment: You need to review how variable scopes work. SO is not a substitute for learning the basics.

Comment: Barmar sir , count is global variable of course.. but it is assigned value 0. The increment() will increase count in the function scope. So, how the second function access count = 1 from the increment() scope ?

Comment: @mdrakibgayen It doesn't; `count` is globally-scoped. All references to `count` in this code reference the only `count` in scope--the same global one.

Comment: @mdrakibgayen *"The increment() will increase count in the function scope"*: No, you would have to **declare** the variable within that function to make it locally scoped to that function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return that value from a function and pass count as argument to the functions:

```
let count = 0;

function increment(count){ 
    count += 1;
    console.log(count);
    return count; 
}

function decrement(count){ 
    count -= 1;
    console.log(count); 
    return count;
}

var value = increment(count);
value = decrement(count);

value = decrement(increment(count)); //no change of course
```

Comment: Why? It's global. Whether or not it *should* be global is a separate discussion, but in the OP it is, and there's no reason to pass it around.